# GAE creating multiple process id of GAE while starting the server

Tags: google-app-engine

when i start the server GAE always create the new prcoess,

**`ant runserver`**

the build.xml

```
  <target name="runserver" depends="datanucleusenhance"
      description="Starts the development server.">
    <dev_appserver war="war" />
  </target>

C:\>netstat -a -n -o | grep 8080
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6496
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2288
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2572
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7240
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1672
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7492
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5660
```

How can i stop the GAE instance using my build.xml scripts, or which command to be used to stop the GAE instanse.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you invoke "ant runserver" in a Console window, the resulting Java process runs in the foreground as the active job.  So in order to stop it you merely have to type Control-C (or Control-BREAK on Windows).

([This page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/ant?hl=en) in the App Engine documentation mentions Control-C.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) regarding Control-BREAK on Windows.)